# To describe crystallity structures of this ferromagnetic material

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science, non-linear-systems, microscopy

MOKE microscope picture of the ferromagnetic Material $Co_{40} Fe_{40} B_{20}$ of 20 nm thin film

[image]

All other pictures look the same, also from different angles: [0,360] by 15 degree separation.

I need to describe its texture and crystalline structures approximately. 
There seems to be some sort of labelling for textures with three numbers from 111 to 123, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_(crystalline)). 
The manufacturing process of the sample determines the texture and its crystalline structures. 
However, I do not know how this material is prepared.

I think you can describe this crystalline structure though the [magnetocrystalline anisotropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetocrystalline_anisotropy). 
Each element has their characteristic anisotropy constants in ferromagnetic materials: Co and Fe. 
Since boron is not a ferromagnetic material, it would not contribute to this crystalline structure. 
Probably, we can therefore say that this material exhibits two ferroic orders where the easy axis points either towards 110 or 111 (but not 100), since we cannot neglect other anisotropy constant.

However, I am not sure how you can describe better the crystalline structure of this material. 
I read somewhere that you can also characterize the crystalline structure by the grain size. 
Here it would be approximately 10 nm. 
How can you estimate it from the picture?

How can you determine the crystalline structure of the ferromagnetic material based on this picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture shows steady mass with low surface irregularities ($\approx$ 1.5 nm). 
The microscope resolution is about 500 nm and its slit size about 1-10 nm so deduced from that.
The sample is amorphous so no magnotocrystalline anisotropy.